# JS to reload parent to iframe with two different servers

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

Hi i am having an issue with a project.

I have two servers

example-internal.com
example-external.com

a page on **example-internal.com** has an iframe that loads **example-external.com**

**example-internal.com** Hold only internal info that is not accessible to the internet just network only

**example-external.com** hold external data that can be accessed

the iframe opens a form that allows the server to send data to it with out causing issues for me.

What i want it to do it once it has posted the data in the iframe php outputs a script to reload the parent but this does not work. i have tried variations of this to check but no deal.

```
$auth = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` VALUES(........)");
if($auth){echo '
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    self.parent.location.reload();
</script>';
}
```

please help im so confuzed it has worked before but it seams on a different server it wont work any ideas people how i can do this. or is this because another server is requesting a reload.

Comment: I had a problem with something sort of like this before. It's a XSS prevention security measure put in place by both browsers and servers. Theres ways around it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291362/cross-site-scripting-with-iframe

Comment: Check out postMessage.  This will only be good to you if you dont need to support old browsers though.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284251/close-iframe-and-refresh-parent-cross-domain  Another more involved alternative is to use a proxy on the first server.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the same origin policy,  meaning that the i-frame is not considered safe because is it from a different domain.

One potentially simple solution to your problem would be to set document.domain on your page that loads in the iframe "example-external.com".

such as:

```
<script>
    document.domain = "example-internal.com";
</script>
```