# How to configure Content-Security-Policy of Helmet package in express to allow cross site iframe and cross site scripting?

Tags: express, iframe, xss, content-security-policy, same-origin-policy

**Updating details to understand more:** *In my project, user uploads html themes. For each user, if they authenticate, I am creating a public static folder for authenticated user in the same theme folder they are requesting. Then there is a editor in the front end where they can edit html theme contents. I am trying to show html themes in the editor using a iframe using the static link from backend. But the problem is I can't add script to the html theme in the iframe. It's saying permission denied. How can I solve this problem?

I am using express in backend and nextjs in frontend. I have added this code in helmet middleware.

```
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        'connect-src': ["'self'", 'http://localhost:3000'],
        'default-src': "'self'",
        'frame-ancestors': ["'self'", 'http://localhost:3000'],
        sandbox: ['allow-forms', 'allow-scripts'],
        'script-src': ["'self'", 'http://localhost:3000'],
 
      },
    },
  })
);
```

For cross site scripting,

```
app.use(xss())
```

But still getting error in iframe.
[image: Nextjs error of cross site scripting]

From Backend I am trying to allow a route to be use in iframe in the frontend. Since, both server have different port in localhost, it's violating cross site embed and scripting. So, I am using helmet and xss package. I need help to configure it.

I am using iframe's onload attribute to check if it is loaded and then injecting another script to the iframe from frontend.

Comment: Cross site iframe access regulated by [Same Origin Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291362/cross-site-scripting-with-iframe), not Content Security Policy (CSP). CSP can protect from XSS, but can't deliberate allow it.

Comment: How to allow some domain to be able to do cross site scripting, in my express server

Comment: "Cross site scripting" mean a "cross domain scripting". Access to the same domain is not counted as cross site scripting. Access between domain <-> it subdomain also can be allowed to bypass CORS.

Comment: In my project, user uploads html themes. For each user, if they authenticate, I am creating a public static folder for authenticated user in the same theme folder they are requesting. Then there is a editor in the front end where they can edit html theme contents. I am trying to show html themes in the editor using a iframe using the static link from backend. But the problem is I can't add script to the html theme in the iframe. It's saying permission denied. How can I solve this problem? Is it clear now? This is the problem I am having

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue of Same Origin Policy, not with Content Security Policy. Helmet package can't help you.

Set the value `document.domain = 'example.com';` (example.com = 'localhost' in your case) both in the iframe and in the main page. It will reset port number to **null** and subdomain `any.example.com` to domain `example.com`, see [test](https://csplite.com/csp/test344/).

If both iframe and main page are on the same domain, you can just set `document.domain = document.domain;`.

Both variants leads [resetting port number to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481251/what-does-document-domain-document-domain-do/1525312#1525312). therefore yoy'll be able to acces iframe with a different port number.